# How do I stop iOS Chrome from dimming on touching a canvas?

Tags: javascript, ios, css, google-chrome, html5-canvas

I have [a webpage using WebGL on a fullscreen canvas](http://twgljs.org/examples/picking.html).

I have this css to stop selection

```
  *, *:before, *:after {
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
  }
```

And I have this code to stop the context menu

```
gl.canvas.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

But when I touch the screen in chrome iOS it dims. Here's gif of the issue first showing chrome iOS, then showing safari iOS.

[image: Imgur]

Or here's a youtube version

https://youtu.be/1Znsehs-n8E

**Note: Ignore the graphics stutter. My screen capture export messed up for some reason**

Notice when in chrome the background flashes gray sometimes. When in Safari it's constantly white. It's that graying in chrome I'm trying to stop.

It's really annoying because just tapping the screen ends up effectively flashing the screen and is really distracting.

## Update

So I started trying starting from scratch and adding parts in. It looks like it's not related to canvas it's related to listing for `click` events.

If I have

```
gl.canvas.addEventListener('click', function() {});
```

It I get the dimming. If I remove that I don't.  Listing for `touchstart` events doesn't cause the dimming

## Update 2

So it's definately **not** unrelated to canvas. If I remove the canvas and just use a div but I'm checking for `click` I get the dimming

These CSS settings did not help

```
* { 
   -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

This worked

```
 elem.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
 });
```

I'm not sure if there's any other repercussions for `preventDefault` on `touchstart`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: This fixed it

```
elem.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Long version: See updates to bottom of question

Answer (score 3):

Try this `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);`

If that doesn't work, try `pointer-events: none;`

Comment: Thanks but neither of those worked. I found at least one work around.

Comment: This was the solution for me.  It's important to note that this needs to be applied to the container with the click/touch event, not necessarily the <canvas> In my case, I needed to add this to the parent container that had the event registered to it. Also.. thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

This is a very late answer, but maybe will be useful for someone. Faced the same issue not on a full-screen canvas in Chrome(only) on windows device with a touchscreen. a workaround is adding a `touchend` event on canvas aside with `touchstart`.

`nativeElement.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  })`